# Как передать аргумент в DialogFragment и вызвать его

Tags: android, dialogfragment

мой FragmentDialog

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment{

final String[] itemsList = {"1", "2", "3"};
static String TAG="log";

public static MyDialog setItems(String title,String[] itemsList){
    MyDialog md=new MyDialog();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("title",title);
    Log.d(TAG, "setItems: 1 "+title);
    bundle.putStringArray("itemsList",itemsList);
    md.setArguments(bundle);
    return md;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String title=this.getArguments().getString("title");
    Log.d(TAG, "setItems: 2 "+title);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(title)
            .setItems(itemsList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                           itemsList[which],
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

в активити вызываю через:

```
myDialog.setItems("Телефони",Phone);
            myDialog.show(manager,"Phone");
```

при клике получаю

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
java.lang.NullPointerException  
  at ********************.MyDialog.onCreateDialog(MyDialog.java:31)  
  at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)  
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)  
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)  
  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)  
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)  
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)  
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)  
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)  
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)  
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)  
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

на 31 строке:

String title=this.getArguments().getString("title");

Comment: `(MyDialog.java:31)  ` - чтонаходится на 31 строке?

Comment: @metalurgus высчитав ручками  - кажется вот это `return builder.create();`

Comment: String title=this.getArguments().getString("title");

Comment: @Asgard, там еще импорты и т. д. Так что ручками вообще безнадежно))

Comment: вот у Вас есть переменная  - `myDialog`, покажите как она объявлена и нет ли случаем такой строки - `MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog();`

Comment: MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(); объявлена полем в MainActivity

Comment: это и есть ваша ошибка. просто объявите переменную и все.

Comment: @ermak0ff все равно, таже самая ошибка

Comment: сделав вот так `MyDialog.setItems("Телефони",Phone)
                        .show(manager,"Phone");` помогло

Comment: @ermak0ff спасибо!!! вы помогли мне осознать свою ошибку

Comment: ну так напишите в чем она была

Comment: повторное вызов экземпляра, за null обертку

Comment: `myDialog` - экземпляр Fragment'a  
`myDialog.setItems("Телефони",Phone);` первый вызов экземпляр передаю агрументы обертки .  
`myDialog.show(manager,"Phone");` второй вызов, за null агрументы обертки и вызов собствено самого Dialog. 
соответственно мы с обертки получали null поэтому и ошибка была.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myDialog - экземпляр Fragment'a myDialog.setItems("Телефони",Phone); первый вызов экземпляр передаю агрументы обертки . myDialog.show(manager,"Phone"); второй вызов, за null агрументы обертки и вызов собствено самого Dialog. соответственно мы с обертки получали null поэтому и ошибка была.

*By user208111*